# How to convert an answer into a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometimes folks (myself included) answer a question with what should have been a comment.  Is there a way to move the inappropriate answer to a comment rather than delete/add it?

Answer (score 5):

Moderators have the ability convert answers to comments. So for now if you flag the comment as needing moderator attention the moderators can convert it to a comment.

Comment: Yep, I do these a lot, very easy to do actually - and flexible too - not 100% sure about the valid/invalid things though - is it valid if it's a valid question/answer or valid as a flag?

Comment: @Chopper3: I was assuming it was valid as a flag ... but now that you ask...

Comment: @Chopper It's valid as a flag. The system uses it to determine if flags from that user are generally right, so it can show them higher in the flag list

Comment: oh good, mild panic over :)

Answer (score 2):

You could flag it for a moderator and ask them to do it.